# Extract string from JSON in C

Tags: c, json, string, memory

I have a function which choose and extract a JSON line. This JSON line will be computed in another function which is supposed to extract the value of it.

```
"key" : "value",
```

I wish to extract *value* without using any library made to manipulate JSON.

My code looks like this so far :

```
char* extractValueInLine(char* line) { 
  if(!verifyLine(line)) // Checks wether line contains 4 quotes or not
    return "";
  int len = strlen( line );
  char* res = NULL;
  unsigned quoteCpt = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (line[i] == '\"')
        quoteCpt++;
    if (quoteCpt == 3) // If 3 quotes has been skipped
    {
        res = malloc((char) sizeof(res) + sizeof(char)); // Adding memory for one char
        if (NULL == res)
            fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        else
        {
            char toAppend[2];
            toAppend[1] = '\0';
            toAppend[0] = line[i];
            strcat(res, toAppend); // Append current char 
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

This is very ugly and not efficient at all since the output is blank instead of being *value*.
Nevertheless I have tried more and more ways to do this, using string library functions and with sscanf, strtok and stuff but it was either not working or easily breakable.
A code which could work even if a blank space were added or missing would be perfect.
If anyone could advise me or tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Why don't you use some library? Or is it part of some assignment?

Comment: `malloc((char) sizeof(res) + sizeof(char))` looks suspicious. `sizeof(res)` is the size of the pointer, not string to be contained there. You shall use something like `malloc(len-i+1)`.

Comment: _len_ contains the size of parameter _line_ which is bigger than _res_ should be. What I want is to add memory for current char iteration by iteration. Also not using library is indeed part of assignment for I have few JSON related code and it seems using one would not be worth.

Comment: One of the things that JSON is good for is automatic de/serialisation.  High level languages like js, java and C# handle this via reflection (automatically working out class and property names).  Without a whole load of wrapper macros, it will be very ugly to implement in C.

Comment: Well so be it, I don't have the choice to use something else than C.

Comment: Instead of returning "", return NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strchr()` to find the position of the quotes. Then, with that information extract the value.

Something like

```
char *q1 = strchr(line, '\"'); /* needs error checking */
char *q2 = strchr(q1 + 1, '\"');
char *q3 = strchr(q2 + 1, '\"');
char *q4 = strchr(q3 + 1, '\"');

/* allocate (q4 - q3) bytes for res */
sprintf(res, "%.*s", (int)(q4 - q3 - 1), q3 + 1);
```

Comment: I just ran your code and the answere was correct.  Though, I am getting this message: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=].. Can you explain how this work?  q4-q3-1 seems to be length of the value and q3+1 is the memory address of the value.  How does the format specifier handle 2 values?

Comment: Cast the value (code edited) to correct the error (and suppress the warning). As for the `.*` in the conversion specifier it consumes an`int` and limits how many characters are copied.

Comment: So this is kind of similar to sprintf(res, "%.3s", q3+1); But .* conversion specifier allows to consume an integer.  Nice!!!! (00)

Comment: Exactly like that! Glad you understood :-)

Comment: @pmg How do you initialize `res` though ? I have tried to `res = malloc(q4 - q3 -1)` which works most of the time but makes the program to fail in some few cases (particularly when using sprintf on large strings).

Comment: @Badda: you need `q4 - q3` (not `q4 - q3 - 1`) bytes to account for the zero string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The issues with your code

1. Missing one } which makes your code return in the first iteration itself.
2. You are allocating new space every time. Which makes it lose the previous contents.

The fix would be

```
char* extractValueInLine(char* line) { 
    int len = strlen( line );
    char* res = malloc(1);
    res[0] = '\0';
    unsigned quoteCpt = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (line[i] == '\"')
            quoteCpt++;
        else if (quoteCpt == 3) {
            res = realloc(res, strlen(res) + sizeof(char) + 1); // Free memory for additional char
            if (NULL == res)
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
            else{
                char toAppend[2];
                toAppend[1] = '\0';
                toAppend[0] = line[i];
                strcat(res, toAppend);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The main change is that I have used `realloc` instead of `malloc` which copies the previous contents and frees the old buffer.

You can see the demo at [Ideone](https://ideone.com/T6Lfij)

Comment: Your solution seem to be working just fine, except that when I modify key and value, I got undefined error half the time, and "Not enough memory" the other half.

Comment: What input did you try?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - realloc() can allocate from current location.  If this is the case, it doesn't necessarily free the old memory.

Comment: @Nguaial yes ofcourse. I meant to say that it is freed if it had to be freed and he doesn't have to worry about freeing. Anyway, this code is very inefficient. I was just trying to fix his program with minimum changes possible.

Comment: `printf("%s", extractCodeInLine("\"xxx\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\""));`
Seems like depending on the length of the string computed, memory goes wild. 
Also with further debugging I have three errors :ntdll!RtlpNtEnumerateSubKey(), ntdll!RtlImageRvaToVa() and ntdll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap()

Comment: Well, the approach of reallocating again and again is not very effecient and can lead to such bugs. Why don't your run two loops. The first loop will just calculate the length of value. Then allocate the required space and then start filling it. I can make the edit if you can't figure out.

Comment: Honestly I realised my code was garbage since the more I failed the more I tried less efficient ways to solve my problem. I think improving garbage instead of just looking for gold is not a viable solution. Thanks anyway for trying to stick to what I have tried to do. I have understood many things about how to deal with memory thanks to you.